# Why is bash's print statement `echo` instead of `print`?

Tags: bash, unix, history

"Print" seems to have good representation across a lot of programming languages, even in older stuff like Fortran (1957).  Why is it that bash (1989) uses `echo` rather than `print` for the function that prints to the screen?

Is there some fascinating history of computing story, or something mundane?  Is the design decision related to the fact that `$ man print` gives me information about whatever MAILCAP is?

Little more research, `echo` appears to have been introduced (as a built-in function) in the original Bourne shell after 1984: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell  Apparently, it existed non-built-in before that.

Update from comments (via Wumpus Q. Wumbley): earliest echo reference this thread has found so far is V3 (1972)

Comment: well `echo` sound much better than `print` but that's not probably the original thing

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the history of computer tools and arbitrary decisions made back then; not a programming issue

Comment: It can't be because of a naming conflict with mailcap. The `echo` command goes back to the beginning of unix. bash was not a brand new language designed in 1989! It was a new implementation of the unix shell, which is much older.

Comment: There is also `printf` in bash. See `help printf`.

Comment: Hi @zneak, there was a tag available specifically for history, so that's what made me think this was an appropriate question for SO.  Try asking a question with the history tag and look at the description---looked like it fit this question exactly.

Comment: The 1984 date is just when a shell was released with echo as a *built in* command. Before that, Bourne shell scripts used the echo command in `/bin`. The builtin is an optimization, not a new language feature.

Comment: I like this question. It makes me wonder if there were any "echo" commands/keywords/functions before unix. The oldest unix echo documentation I can find is from V3 (1972). http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V3/man/man1/echo.1

Comment: Since I have run out of facts, here's some speculation: if unix was the first to use the name "echo", it was because the unix shell was the first language where printing a string was outsourced to an external program, because unix was the first system to say "processes are cheap, let's use lots of them".

Comment: I get the motive to close since I'm not asking anyone for code, but I think it's still valid under the scope as a question relevant to: "* software tools commonly used by programmers
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: Unix quite likely uses `echo` to print arguments because Multics did.  From http://www.multicians.org/mge.html: echo - Command that prints its arguments on standard_output. The first command executed by Multics at the Phase One milestone in December 1967.

Comment: fascinating!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Semantically, `echo` is not the same as what a `print` statement can be in a programming language. `echo` is a simple program that outputs the same input it gets, which within bash scripts is very useful for print stuff, but it's not its purpose.

`print` in most program languages are a shortcut to `write to stdout`. That happens to print to a console but can also print to a file or to a printer. IMHO, they are conceptually different and can't be comparable.

Comment: `echo` can also "print to a file or to a printer".

Comment: Also, the bash manual page recommends using `printf` instead of `echo`, but won't obsolesce `echo` because of it's wide-spread use.